# org.apache.commons.beanutils copyProperties ignore fields

Tags: java

I am using Java 7 and `org.apache.commons.beanutils`.

Is it possible to copy the beans, but ignore specific fields?

e.g. I have the following:

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

   BeanUtils.copyProperties(personDetails, person);
```

But would like to not copy a member variable in `person` called `password`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to ignore some fields in an object using BeanUtils.copyproperties in spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470579/how-to-ignore-some-fields-in-an-object-using-beanutils-copyproperties-in-spring)

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thanks for the reply, but I am not using Spring, so have `org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils` and not `BeanUtils` from Spring. So the suggested solution will not work.  If you marked this as close, please revert because your solution is not sutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apapche beanutils doesn't give an option to ignore a property while copying.
However, you can use the overloaded method that can copy a single property and repeat for all the properties that you want to copy -

```java
public static void copyProperty(Object bean,
                                String name,
                                Object value)
                         throws IllegalAccessException,
                                InvocationTargetException
```

This copies the specified property value to the specified destination bean, performing any type conversion that is required.

If you use spring's BeanUtil, it has an option to ignore properties -

```
copyProperties(Object source, Object target, String... ignoreProperties)
Copy the property values of the given source bean into the given target bean, ignoring the given "ignoreProperties".
```